# Given a parametrized test, how can I print a message just once for all the parameters?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Assume this sample code:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('foo', ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3'])
def test_foo(foo):
    print('Testing foo')
    data = ['bar1', 'foo1', 'bar2']
    assert foo in data, 'Error: {} is not in data'.format(foo)
```

When running pytest, the output will be:

```
Testing foo
Testing foo
Error: foo2 is not in data
Testing foo
Error: foo3 is not in data
```

Is it possible to display the testing message just once for all the parameters so that the output is:

```
Testing foo
Error: foo2 is not in data
Error: foo3 is not in data
```

My actual code uses like 10 parameters so repeating the message 10 times gets pretty annoying and adds a lot of noise to the output.

Comment: `if foo == 'bar1': print('Endpoint')`?

Comment: @hoefling either I didn't understand your comment or you didn't understand my question. I changed the sample code, just to make it simpler.

Comment: I mean I would just make a conditional print in `test_foo` that is invoked only once, for example when `foo` arg is `bar1`.

Comment: ahhh, that totally hacks it! xD

Comment: This seems like one of the few good use cases for global variables. Outside `test_foo`: `foo_tested = False`; inside: `global foo_tested; if not foo_tested: print('testing foo'); foo_tested = True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized this question makes no sense at all. Even if there is only one test, each parameter converts it in an independent test instance, so it doesn't make sense to just display a message once per test.

The output is correct, because it's similar to:

```
====== test_foo(foo2) ======
Testing foo
Error: foo2 is not in data

====== test_foo(foo3) ======
Testing foo
Error: foo3 is not in data
```

Anyway, to answer my question, both approaches of @hoefling and @BallpointBen work. Personally I prefer @BallpointBen's way because you don't need to match the `if` against a parameter that at some time you may decide to remove.